# Directing from a 1und1 hosting solution, with URLs intact

Tags: web-hosting, redirects

I have done this before on GoDaddy without a hitch, but I cannot seem to figure out this particular case.

I have a domain space with temporary URL `http://yogainun.mysubname.com` and am hosting the domain name that is to be applied to it at `1und1.de`. Right now I have set it up so that from the 1und1 domain name hosting the address `http://www.yoga-in-unternehmen.de` is frame redirected to the subdomain that I just referred to.

But this is not what I want.

`http://www.yoga-in-unternehmen.de` is to be the domain. With the frame redirect, URL's like `http://www.yoga-in-unternehmen.de/example-article` do not show up. But this is what I want.

With GoDaddy in a similar case, I just turned on DNS and changed the name servers. That worked without problem, but with 1und1 not. Is there something I am missing?

Answer (score 1):

With cPanel type hosting it's called an addon domain and what it's doing behind the scenes is a redirect. Do you have the option to configure an addon domain or can you do a redirect like this:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !=yoga-in-unternehmen.de
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://yoga-in-unternehmen.de/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Answer (score 1):

Hopefully this will help http://faq.1and1.com/domains/domain_admin/dns_settings/9.html can you not open a support ticket?

Answer (score 1):

Currently, you seem to have two domains: `yoga-in-unternehmen.de` with DNS and website hosted by 1&1, and `yogainunternehmen.de` hosted by some other host.  The first domain currently only returns a frameset that loads the actual content from the second host.

As you correctly note, this is not a very good arrangement.  (I won't enumerate the reasons here — it should suffice to note that there are very few problems for which HTML frames are the correct solution.)  What *is* the correct answer depends on just what you want to achieve, and what features your hosting providers support:

If you want to keep the actual content hosted at `yogainunternehmen.de`, but have `yoga-in-unternehmen.de` be the domain seen by users, one solution is to [add a CNAME DNS record](http://faq.1and1.com/domains/domain_admin/dns_settings/14.html) from `yoga-in-unternehmen.de` (and `www.yoga-in-unternehmen.de`) to `yogainunternehmen.de`.

If the hosting provider for `yogainunternehmen.de` is using [name-based virtual hosting](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_hosting#Name-based) (which they most likely are), you'll also need to let them know that `yoga-in-unternehmen.de` is now an alias for `yogainunternehmen.de`.  (In fact, you should do this first, *before* adding the CNAME record.)  This may be possible from their control panel, or you may need to contact them personally.

Finally, you should add a [HTTP 301 redirect](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_301) from `yogainunternehmen.de` to `yoga-in-unternehmen.de`, so that you won't be serving duplicate content from the two domains.  As the websites for both domains are now served from the same host, you can do this entirely there.  Some hosting providers may let you do this entirely from their control panel; otherwise, if you have (or can add) an [.htaccess file](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Htaccess) in your website root directory for `yogainunternehmen.de` (which is also now serving `yoga-in-unternehmen.de`), and the webserver supports [mod_rewrite](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html), you can use the following ruleset:

```
# Standard preamble for mod_rewrite in root .htaccess file:
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
Options +FollowSymLinks

# Redirect to yoga-in-unternehmen.de if accessed via some other hostname:
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !=yoga-in-unternehmen.de
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://yoga-in-unternehmen.de/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Alternatively, instead of using CNAME, you could just move both domains to the same DNS and web hosting provider (it doesn't even have to be either of your current providers), and have them configure them as aliases of each other.  This might be cheaper than maintaining two separate hosting accounts.  For the practical details of arranging that, I'd suggest asking the hosting provider you want to move to — they'll have a financial incentive to help you as much as possible.  You will still most likely want to retain both domains, and have one serve 301 redirects to the other, just so that you won't break any existing links to your site and won't lose any search engine rank.